# What is the best way of storing date?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am a new to storing dates based on time zones.

Need to know the standard way to store the date in the datastore.

My requirements are

1. Easy to query  the date based on the date range.
2. show the date with the client appropriate time zone selected by him(I am having a table maintained for the timezone separately)
3. Able to query using the datastore Admin console also.

Any suggestions/ideas regarding this will be a great help in proceeding further.

Comment: store the date and time with a zone offset (for the timezone).  Timezone is an ISO standard.

Comment: if i store it in the default UTC I can convert them when showing it in the view right ?

Comment: yes. I believe simpledateformat has a zone offset character (Z I think).

Comment: So again why would i need the time zone as offset ?
Are you working with google appengine. It need it to be easy to query both using the java program i code as well as the datastore viewer.

Comment: the Zone offset is a delta to convert the time to the "local time" in the zone.  for example "13:00 -0300" is 1300 hours in the time zone that is -3 hours from gmt.  I believe that means 1300 hours gmt and 1000 hours "local"

Comment: you need the zone offset so you can determine the relationship between two times in different zones.  for example "1200 -0300" and "1300 -0400" are the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Always convert and store data/time in UTC so the data become easily understandable and non-ambiguous

Only convert the date/time back to "local time" of the user for displaying purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to store dates in UTC/GMT equivalent millisecond format. On the result of which it will be easy to convert back and forth to appropriate time zone based on offset either  from UI or server side. I believe date in database should be zone independent to avoid unnecessary​ complexity.

The best/easy way to handle zone conversation is from UI using JavaScript, as clients side will be always local time. There are multiple JS plugins available to handle this.

Here is one [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)